# Abel's theorem on continuity of power series

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
It's Abel's theorem sbout continuity of power series at endpoint interval of convergence $(-R,R)$ (to simplicity of notation Rudin takes $R=1$).
I have to questions:

**1)** I guess that we must consider $\lim \limits_{x\to 1-} f(x)$. Because $f(x)$ is undefined on right neightborhood of point $x=1$.

**2)** Also there we must consider $1-\delta<x\leqslant 1$.

**3)** I think that there suitable  $\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sum \limits_{n=0}^{N}|s_n-s||x|^n}.$

Dear users! What do you thinks about my above remarks?

Comment: 1) Correct. 2) Correct. 3) The definition of $\delta$ should not contain $x$.

Comment: Ohhh sure! But we can take $\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sum \limits_{n=0}^{N}|s_n-s|}.$ Right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: @Winther, Thanks a lot for your remark!